# Can feature selection algorithms be used with columns containing categorical values?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

Can feature selection algorithms in Scikit-Learn or in other machine learning python modules be used with categorical values in dataset?

Comment: Question still too broad after edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. If your column is categorical, you need to encode it 
into numerical representation. If your column consist of textual entries, you would first need to transform this text into numerical vectors - check *bag of words* or *tf-idf* for example.

Comment: Thank you a lot for alleviating my doubt. By the way, is there anything to make encoding easier? Or can I just convert categorical columns into numbers? 

Some of the things I can think of are to use get_dummies function, countvectorizer and astype(cat code) which are from pandas. Am I right?